# NodeJS Facebook User Feed Subscriptions: Invalid OAuth access token

Tags: node.js, facebook, oauth

Am close to tearing my hair out (as a passionate developer, should), so hopefully I can get some help on this one.  After reading a bunch of forums and sifting through facebook documentation, here is a log file of trying to make a subscription to user feed's.  I really only need to know if the bottom set of API's I am running should work in theory.  Here is my log:

```
*********************************************************
makeRequest - Host: graph.facebook.com - Path: /v2.2/{ app_id }/subscriptions?object=user
*********************************************************
Type: DELETE
*********************************************************
Wed Feb 25 2015 12:52:15 GMT+0000 (UTC) Server is listening on port 81
*********************************************************
makeRequest - Host: graph.facebook.com - Path: /oauth/access_token?client_id={ app_id }&client_secret={ app_secret }&grant_type=client_credentials
*********************************************************
Type: GET
*********************************************************
App Access Token: { app_token }
*********************************************************
makeRequest - Host: graph.facebook.com - Path: /v2.2/{ app_id }/subscriptions?&object=user&fields=feed&callback_url={ uri_encoded_ callback_url }&verify_token={ verify_token }&access_token={ app_token }
*********************************************************
Type: POST
*********************************************************
Success: {"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190}}
```

So here I am first trying to delete any subscriptions currently active, then using the API to get issued a new application access token, and finally to make a new subscription.  Here is my function to initialize this whole process:

```
function subscribe_facebook(http,https) {
    var oauth_obj   = getOauthObj('facebook');

    // First Delete
    var url         = oauth_obj.subscription_url;
    var host        = splitUrl(url,"host");
    var path        = splitUrl(url,"path");

    path += "?object=user";

    makeRequest(http,host,path,80,'DELETE',function(ret){
        // Get App Access Token
        url         = oauth_obj.access_token_url;
        host        = splitUrl(url,"host");
        path        = splitUrl(url,"path");

        path    +=  "?client_id="       +   oauth_obj.app_id;
        path    +=  "&client_secret="   +   oauth_obj.app_secret;
        path    +=  "&grant_type=client_credentials";

        makeRequest(https,host,path,443,'GET',function(ret){
            facebook_app_token = ret.toString().split('|');
            facebook_app_token = facebook_app_token[1];
            consoleLogger("App Access Token: " + facebook_app_token);

            subscribe(https,'facebook',443,'POST',facebook_app_token,myServer);
        });
    });
}
```

And here is the subscribe function it enters:

```
function subscribe(http,type,port,method,access_token,myServer) {
    var oauth_obj = getOauthObj(type);
    var sub_post_data = "";
    switch (type) {
        case "facebook":
            sub_post_data = 
                "&object="          +   "user"+
                "&fields="          +   "feed"+
                "&callback_url="    +   encodeURIComponent(myServer + "/" + type) +
                "&verify_token="    +   "*****" +
                "&access_token="    +   access_token
            break;
    }

    var host = splitUrl(oauth_obj.subscription_url,"host");
    var path = splitUrl(oauth_obj.subscription_url,"path");
    path += "?" + sub_post_data;

    makeRequest(http,host,path,port,method,function(ret) {
        consoleLogger("Success: " + ret);
    });
}
```

I made this other function to maintain the social media variables:

```
function getOauthObj(type) {
    var obj = {};
    var authorize_url = "";
    var access_token_url = "";
    var request_token_url = "";
    var subscription_url = "";

    var app_id = "";
    var app_secret = "";

    var main_domain = "";
    var scope = "";

    switch (type) {
        case "facebook":
            app_id      = '*****';
            app_secret  = '**********';

            main_domain         = 'https://graph.facebook.com/';
            authorize_url       = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth';
            access_token_url    = main_domain + 'oauth/access_token';
            request_token_url   = main_domain + '2.2/me';
            subscription_url    = main_domain + "v2.2/" + app_id + "/subscriptions";
            scope               = 'read_stream';
            break;
    }
    obj.main_domain         = main_domain;

    obj.authorize_url       = authorize_url;
    obj.access_token_url    = access_token_url;
    obj.request_token_url   = request_token_url;
    obj.subscription_url    = subscription_url;

    obj.app_id              = app_id;
    obj.app_secret          = app_secret;

    return obj;
}
```

Being that the OAuth is invalid, I'm assuming that I'm not passing the right parameters to the oauth API to do this or not - can someone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: You should also add what the actual problem is... Respectively show some code. The error obviously states that the App Access Token is invalid.

Comment: @Tobi - Yes, I can update it now with some code, but I thought the obvious problem was in the order I was getting and using API's.  Previously, I did not know about the requirement of first getting an application access token, and ultimately only trying to make a subscription using the user's access token (for object=user&fields=feed).  And yes, the error obviously states the OAuth token is invalid, but the two part question to this is why, and which token does it refer; does it mean the app access token just issued(?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, well it's fixed now.  I have read on some forums about different Facebook API's which details that using the application id, concatenated with a pipe, then the application secret can be used in place of an access token, but I didn't think this could be used here, but turns out it can!

```
*********************************************************
makeRequest - Host: graph.facebook.com - Path: /v2.2/{ app_id }/subscriptions?&object=user&fields=feed&callback_url={ callback_url }&verify_token={ verify_token }&access_token={ app_id }|{ app_secret }
```

Hopefully this helps someone.

Cheers.