# Facebook User Feed Subscriptions

Tags: javascript, facebook, subscription

I have what I'm sure will be a very easy question, I'm just confused.

I have [successfully got my server subscribed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719916/nodejs-facebook-user-feed-subscriptions-invalid-oauth-access-token), for real time [user/feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.2) but simply am not getting any updates.

I have logged myself in using the `FB.login` JavaScript SDK, using the scope `"user_about_me,user_status,read_stream"` - so I expected to see updates for my user, but not getting anything at all.

The app is in "Development Mode", so, can anyone confirm that since I have got a `{ success: true }`, that the reason is simply because of this? Or perhaps I need to put it under review from Facebook?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a little bit useless, because you'll never get `read_stream` approved for a normal app...

Comment: So; to answer the question, what I am missing is that it just needs to be an approved app, is that correct?

Comment: No, if the user you're testing this with is the apps admin/developer/tester, it should theoretically work. But for taking this live, the permissions need to be approved by FB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woo, it's fixed now!

On my research, I had come across this post:

[How to subscribe to real-time updates for a Facebook page's wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367948/how-to-subscribe-to-real-time-updates-for-a-facebook-pages-wall)

Not realizing that I can use the USER_ID in place of the PAGE_ID.  Following the [Real Time Subscription](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/app/subscriptions) documentation, I thought that by using the APP_ID, that it would allow to make one subscription for all users that grant the application its scope.

On to the next hurdle...